# Using Selenium to scrape values from a single table with no ID, on a page with multiple similar tables

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape values from a table on a notion.so page. I have been using Selenium to wait for the class `notion-table-cell-text` to load, and then getting the data with `get_attribute("innerText")`. This worked when it was the only table on the page, but I cannot figure out how to do it now that other tables are present. The table does not seem to have a distinct ID or any way I can find to uniquely identify it. In this particular instance, I would like to scrape values from the first table on the page. If possible, I'd also like to know how I can scrape any other table in a situation like this, not necessarily just the first one.

This is the code that worked originally - it now times out attempting to retrieve the table:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://theiagen.notion.site/Docker-Image-and-Reference-Materials-for-SARS-CoV-2-Genomic-Characterization-98328c61f5cb4f77975f512b55d09108'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.get(url)
button = driver.execute_script(document.get)
notion_table = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerText") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notion-table-cell-text']")))]

workspace_keys = set(['Pangolin Docker Image','Nextclade Docker Image','Nextclade Dataset Tag','VADR Docker Image'])
workspace_val_indices = [i for i, item in enumerate(notion_table) if item in workspace_keys]
workspace_val_indices = [i+1 for i in workspace_val_indices]
ws_update_vals = [notion_table[i] for i in workspace_val_indices]
ws_update_vals = [val.strip('"') for val in ws_update_vals]
```

I've attached a screenshot of what I see when I inspect the second table as requested - the link to the site I'm trying to scrape is also included in the code above.

[image: inspecting the second table]

Comment: _other tables are present. The table does not seem to have a distinct ID_: Update the question with the text based HTML of other tables.

Comment: There are only two tables - added a screenshot of the HTML for the second one. As far as I can tell, the HTML is identical for both of them, but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that once more tables were added, all the tables were hidden by dropdown menus. My solution was to find the first dropdown button and expand it like this:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-label='Open']"))).click()`

This solves my immediate problem, so I'll mark this question as solved. I'm still not sure what the best practice would be for selecting elements further down the page when none of the divs seem to have distinct IDs. I imagine you could do something like "target the nth instance that matches class=xxxx", but I feel like there must be a more robust way of doing this that wouldn't break down whenever the number/order of targeted elements changes.